# Disappearing string in intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have something strange going on with my application.
I am trying to send a string via Broadcast by doing the following:

1st step (Sending):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("INFO");
    intent.putExtra("INFO_VALUE", "hello_world_2019");
```

2nd step (Receiving):

```
       if ("INFO".equals(intent.getAction())) {
                String abc = intent.getStringExtra("INFO_VALUE");
                Log.i(TAG, "" + abc);
        }
```

Doing the previous steps, I get a null into my `abc` field. Also, if I use the debugger and check my intent related to the second step, I get:

```
intent -> mExtras -> mMap -> value[0] -> name: "hello_world_2019"
```

I am confused to what is going on. The `abc` field is not supposed to be null, but it is in this case.

How can I populate the aforementioned field so it is not null ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Please show how the `Intent` gets from the first code snippet to the second one. Is this `Intent` being used directly in a `sendBroadcast()` call? Or is it wrapped in a `PendingIntent` that is used somewhere else? We need more context in order to help you. The code you've posted looks fine, the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Please explain what exactly you are trying to do, if you want to send data from one activity to other than my friend this is not the correct way to do that.

If you want to send a broadcast and receive that somewhere inside your code than you need to follow the below steps:

**ReceiverActivity.java**

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  ... 

  // Register to receive messages. 
  // We are registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive Intents 
  // with actions named "custom-event-name". 
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("INFO"));
} 

// Our handler for received Intents. This will be called whenever an Intent 
// with an action named "custom-event-name" is broadcasted. 
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override 
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Get extra data included in the Intent 
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
  } 
}; 

@Override 
protected void onDestroy() { 
  // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed. 
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  super.onDestroy(); 
}
```

**SenderActivity.java**

```
 private void sendMessage() { 
  Log.d("sender", "Broadcasting message");
  Intent intent = new Intent("INFO");
  // You can also include some extra data. 
  intent.putExtra("message", "Message goes here!");
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```